# Poor proxmox pveperf performance on a mdadm raid 1

Tags: debian, performance, hard-drive, proxmox

When running pveperf on a Debian + Proxmox PowerEdge R540 server that uses two hard drive in a raid 1 configuration (using mdadm), I get very low performances in the number of FSYNCS/SECOND:

```
$ sudo pveperf /home/proxmox/
CPU BOGOMIPS:      134426.56
REGEX/SECOND:      2896824
HD SIZE:           749.94 GB (/dev/mapper/ProtoMolecule--vg-home)
BUFFERED READS:    107.51 MB/sec
AVERAGE SEEK TIME: 124.28 ms
FSYNCS/SECOND:     4.66
DNS EXT:           38.19 ms
```

How could I go about finding why it's this low? The disks are 7200 rpm 1TB TOSHIBA MG04ACA1, so my guess would be it should be higher. The seeking time and dns ext also seem high.

I cannot test directly on my disks the speed of pveperf as I already have data on the disks.

For the records, on my proxmox installation on another dedicated server, a Kimsufi KS-8, those are the results:

```
$ sudo pveperf
CPU BOGOMIPS:      42669.28
REGEX/SECOND:      1494300
HD SIZE:           1833.16 GB (/dev/sda2)
BUFFERED READS:    85.77 MB/sec
AVERAGE SEEK TIME: 14.43 ms
FSYNCS/SECOND:     55.80
DNS EXT:           10.44 ms
```

How could I start finding out what are the cause of those poor performances ?

Comment: Did you do any performance tuning, such as https://kruyt.org/linux-disk-tuning/ ?

Comment: Not really, I just have relatime and nobarrier for my mounted location. I did use fio to check the read and write speeds, and the results are poor.  For random read ( fio --randrepeat=1 --ioengine=libaio --direct=1 --gtod_reduce=1 --name=test --filename=test --bs=4k --iodepth=64 --size=4G --readwrite=randwrite ) the ETA is ~1h30…